# shell strange characters

Tags: shell-command

When running M-x shell I get strange additional characters.

It looks like this,

[image]

I should look similar to how it does in the terminal,

[image]

I am very new to Emacs. Hopefully there is a simple fix.

I am running Fedora 25 and GNU Emacs 25.1.1

Comment: you might want to look at this :- http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175770

Comment: maybe that: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Shell#Fix.2C_add_colors_and_highlight_text

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your shell configuration. It's sending [escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence) to color parts of the prompt, to set the terminal sequence, etc. But the terminal of `M-x shell` is a very basic one that doesn't understand these escape sequences. You need to turn off all these features.

The basic way to detect the terminal capabilities is to query the `TERM` variable. Under `M-x shell`, its value is `dumb`. Turn off all prompt formatting and other similar configuration when `$TERM` is `dumb`.

For example, if your shell is bash, use something like in your `.bashrc`:

```
if [[ "$TERM" == "dumb" ]]; then
  # No terminal escape sequences, only prompt escapes
  PS1='\u at \h in \w\n\$ '
else
  # Assuming a rich terminal, using terminal escape sequences
  PS1='\e]2;\w\a\e]1;\W\a\u at \h in \w\n\$ '
fi
```

Comment: M-x eshell  
works great for me.
Thanks