# clean weird characters from org source shell

Tags: org-babel, shell, control-characters

When I run a shell command in Org I sometimes get back weird control characters:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output :session test
guix pull
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
: Updating channel 'guix' from Git repository at 'https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/guix.git'...
: Building from this channel:
:   guix      https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/guix.git 258a27e
: Computing Guix derivation for 'x86_64-linux'...  ^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\^H|^H/^H-^H\
: nothing to be done
```

It's not just `^H`, but many others. I can replace them if I have them present. However, I can't store them in a regex within a clean-up function because it's not clear how to encode the file it's saved in.

Answers to [similar questions](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/50546/my-terminal-emacs-displays-weird-characters-u2506-for-unvisiable-characters-i) have suggested to check locale. I would think this should be okay:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output :session test
export | grep LANG
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: export GDM_LANG="en_US.utf8"
: export LANG="en_US.utf8"
```

[Others](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/shell-strange-characters) [have](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27184/shell-strange-characters) suggested changing `PS1` in `.bashrc`. These made no difference. It seems the shell used by Org is already stripped down:

```
#+begin_src sh :results output :session test
echo $PS1
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 
: \s-\v\$
```

Still [more](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19848/weird-characters-in-shell-mode-with-zsh) have suggested [bracketed paste mode](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Bracketed-Paste-Mode) may be a factor. It may be, but definitely not for the `guix pull` above. As far as I understand, bracketed paste mode is only for  `ESC [ 2 0 0 ~ ,` and `ESC [ 2 0 1 ~ .`. I have not seen these or, at the very least can't reproduce them.

I'm at a loss for how to clean up these control characters or, better yet, not produce them in the first place. Any advice?

Comment: Do `guix pull > guix.out 2>&1` and check the output file with `M-x find-file-literally`. If that includes the weird characters, then you have to filter the output of `guix pull`. Maybe there is an option to turn the weird characters off. The `^H-` suggests that it's trying to produce an overstrike effect.

Answer (score 1):

guix is making a spinner by printing a character, backspacing over it, and printing something else. Programs are only supposed to do these things if they have reason to believe that their output is going to a terminal. Since `org-mode` is not a terminal, guix shouldn’t be doing this. It might be a bug you should report to them at https://issues.guix.gnu.org/, but it could just be that it thinks that it is in a terminal.

What is `TERM` getting set to in the subprocess?

```
#+begin_src sh :results output
echo $TERM
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: dumb
```

If it is anything other than “dumb”, then you should check your shell startup files to see if you’re explicitly setting it to something else. This is quite common, but always a mistake. You should allow your terminal to set it for you, and then leave it alone.